# How to check if user activated glances for your watch app

Tags: ios, apple-watch

Image you have a Apple Watch App and you provide a glance for your App.
The user can deactivate your glance in his Watch app on his iPhone:

[image: Watch App on iPhone]

Is it possible to check if the user triggered "Show in Glances" for your App? If so, how can you check it?